# Vault approle authentication fails through API

Tags: airflow, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

So I am using vault approle with airflow as secret backend and it keeps throwing permission denied error on *$Vault_ADDR/v1/auth/approle/login*. I tried using approle from CLI like:

```
vault write auth/approle/login role_id="$role_id" secret_id="$secret_id"
```

and it works fine.
But if I try it using API:

```
curl --request POST --data @payload.json $VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/approle/login
```

where payload.json contains secret and role id. It fails with permission denied.

Here is my policy:

```
vault policy write test-policy -<<EOF

path "kv/data/airflow/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read", "list" ]
}
EOF
```

It works fine for reading on this path.
and role:

```
vault write auth/approle/role/test-role token_ttl=4h token_max_ttl=5h token_policies="test-policy"
```

Don't know why it is failing with API.
An important thing to mention is that I am using cloud based HCP Vault.

Comment: If you are interfacing through the CLI and API with the same entity, then this means there is an issue in the transmitted `data`.

Comment: Well, I found the issue as mentioned in answer below. Vault has different behaviour for self hosted and HCP Vault. Though it isn't mentioned in any docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your app_role authentication.You need to provide admin namespace in your url.
Change this:
curl --request POST --data @payload.json $VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/approle/login
To this:
curl --request POST --data @payload.json $VAULT_ADDR/v1/admin/auth/approle/login

Furthermore, if you are trying to access from a third party tool like airflow then try adding "namespace=admin" in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. HCP vault uses namespace (default = admin). Namespace was needed in url :

```
$VAULT_ADDR/v1/admin/auth/approle/login
```

but the problem still exists in Airflow's Hashicorp provider. Changing the auth_mount_point still concatenates it at the end as :

```
$VAULT_ADDR/v1/auth/{$auth_mount_point}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get it working in Airflow?

Comment: @Alexander, I didn't get to try it again in airflow, but got it working in astronomer using namespace=admin config.